# how to install cPanel on docker

Tags: docker, centos, cpanel, servermanager

we have a host with Centos 7 and we installed Docker for use a container we use custom image that this custom image has active systemd . but we can not install cPanel in container. Tnx for you'r help.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel doesn't have a documentation for running inside a docker container so it might not work.
This should be tested.
However, cPanel has a documentation for running inside linux containers:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/76Docs/Linux+Containers

Comment: If you are flexible about the hosting control panel, you can use the Plesk docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/plesk/plesk/